# How to convert a C binary buffer to it’s hex representation in Python string?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cython, pypy

It’s well known pysha3 isn’t compatible with pypy, and because it’s unmaintained for 3 years, I have to modify it myself.

Of course, a proper way would be to perform a complete rewrite in pure python code (which would also results in a faster implementation over the current one), but I lack the required knowledge both in cryptograhy and background math to do this, and the program using it is very very list intensive (which requires a python3 without a gil for multithreading or python3 with a jit).

The single point of failure [boils down to this function](https://github.com/tiran/pysha3/blob/master/Modules/_sha3/backport.inc) which has to be called by C code:

```
static PyObject*
_Py_strhex(const char* argbuf, const Py_ssize_t arglen)
{
    static const char *hexdigits = "0123456789abcdef";

    PyObject *retval;
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    Py_UCS1 *retbuf;
#else
    char *retbuf;
#endif
    Py_ssize_t i, j;

    assert(arglen >= 0);
    if (arglen > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX / 2)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    retval = PyUnicode_New(arglen * 2, 127);
    if (!retval)
            return NULL;
    retbuf = PyUnicode_1BYTE_DATA(retval);
#else
    retval = PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, arglen * 2);
    if (!retval)
            return NULL;
    retbuf = PyString_AsString(retval);
    if (!retbuf) {
            Py_DECREF(retval);
            return NULL;
    }
#endif
    /* make hex version of string, taken from shamodule.c */
    for (i=j=0; i < arglen; i++) {
        unsigned char c;
        c = (argbuf[i] >> 4) & 0xf;
        retbuf[j++] = hexdigits[c];
        c = argbuf[i] & 0xf;
        retbuf[j++] = hexdigits[c];
    }

    return retval;
}
```

cython compatibility level is at 3.2 for pypy and `PyUnicode_New` was introduced in python3.3.

I tried the hammer way to fix it with replacing the whole file with the following cython code:

```
cdef Py_strhex(const char* argbuf, const Py_ssize_t arglen):
    return (argbuf[:arglen]).hex()
```

but it seems it triggers a segmentation fault including compiling and using the official Python implementation. And using the official PyPy binary, I don’t have the debugging symbols for gdb so I don’t know why.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff564cd00 in pypy_g_text_w__pypy_interpreter_baseobjspace_W_Root () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#1  0x00007ffff5d721a8 in pypy_g_getattr () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#2  0x00007ffff543a8bd in pypy_g_dispatcher_15 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#3  0x00007ffff5ab909b in pypy_g_wrapper_second_level.star_2_14 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#4  0x00007fffd7212372 in _Py_strhex.2738 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/site-packages/pysha3-1.0.3.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/_pysha3.pypy3-72-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#5  0x00007fffd7217990 in _sha3_sha3_224_hexdigest_impl.2958 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/site-packages/pysha3-1.0.3.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/_pysha3.pypy3-72-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#6  0x00007ffff5be2170 in pypy_g_generic_cpy_call__StdObjSpaceConst_funcPtr_SomeI_5 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#7  0x00007ffff54b25cd in pypy_g.call_1 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#8  0x00007ffff56715b9 in pypy_g_BuiltinCodePassThroughArguments1_funcrun_obj () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#9  0x00007ffff56ffc06 in pypy_g_call_valuestack__AccessDirect_None () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
#10 0x00007ffff5edb29b in pypy_g_CALL_METHOD__AccessDirect_star_1 () from /usr/lib64/pypy3.6-v7.2.0-linux64/bin/libpypy3-c.so
```

Increasing the default Linux stack depth to 65Mb doesn’t change the depth of recursion where the segfault happens so even if the stack depth is larger than 200, this doesn’t seems to be related to a stack overflow.

Comment: Any chance of updating your codebase to Python 3.6 or higher?

Comment: @Selcuk PyPy support python3.6, but only at the python level. At the C level, it’s still at level 3.2 of compatibility. Even the latest version of lack the functions to run pysha3.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about using the built-in `hashlib.sha3` that comes with Python 3.6.

Comment: @Selcuk it’s for doing the keccak variant of sha3 in order to be compatible with Ethereum so it’s unfortunately not compatible. The project itself doesn’t use pysha3: it’s used by many many pip dependencies so fixing this issue would be simpler.

Comment: I don't know why you say at C level it's still at level 3.2.  Maybe it misses a specific API function, but this is a bug that we'd fix if you report it.

Comment: Sorry, it seems it was already reported long ago (https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2723/undefined-symbol-pyunicode_new-in-pypy3).  We should look at it again now.

Comment: @ArminRigo And basically,it’s been reopened since may. I can’t wait years to get this function implemented by PyPy or pysha3 to be implemented properly in Rpython. I need the result of huge graph walking now and done fast (which excludes Cpython) !

Comment: Sure, I understand the problem.  I just wanted to say that the bitbucket issue was filed long ago, but at that point both PyPy3 and the PyUnicode_New() function were not as widely used.  Nowadays we're more actively fixing C-extension-module-level issues on PyPy3.

Comment: @ArminRigo an unrelated question: would numba work on top of pypy? I’m especially thinking about it’s GILless threading feature.

Comment: We are also working on fixing numba, which similarly uses a few minor C-API functions not implemented yet on PyPy3.  I can't guarantee that it'll work then, but changes are good.

Comment: No, see comment by Ronan here: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/3107/please-expose-_py_finalizing-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found what I was looking for using this variant.
This won’t work on all compilers and is compatible only with Python3 but it brings partial PyPy compatibility (some tests which are supposed to fails succeeds because an Incorrect hash is returned) with pysha3 alongs the programs it depends on:

```
static PyObject * _Py_strhex(const char* argbuf, const Py_ssize_t arglen) {
    static const char *hexdigits = "0123456789abcdef";

    assert(arglen >= 0);

    if (arglen > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX / 2)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();

    const Py_ssize_t len=arglen*2;
    char retbuf[len+1];
    retbuf[len+1]=0;

    /* make hex version of string, taken from shamodule.c */
    for (Py_ssize_t i=0,j=0; i < arglen; i++) {
        retbuf[j++] = hexdigits[(argbuf[i] >> 4) & 0xf];
        retbuf[j++] = hexdigits[argbuf[i] & 0xf];
    }

    return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(retbuf,len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the Cython, it's simpler than you think:

```
cdef Py_strhex(const char* argbuf, const Py_ssize_t arglen):
    return (argbuf[:arglen]).hex()
```

Essentially you don't need to `malloc` (which was introducing a memory leak anyway because it was missing a `free`) and you don't need the `memcpy`. `argbuf[:arglen]` creates a `bytes` object with the appropriate length (making a copy of the data).

This definitely works on CPython. On PyPy2 it produces `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hex'`, which is correct for Python 2. I'd imagine if it were to produce a segmentation fault it would happen before the `AttributeError` so that's promising. I don't have PyPy3 readily available...

---

**Edit**:

I've now managed to test my code on PyPy3 like follows:

```
# extra Cython code just to call the function
def test():
    cdef const char* a = "0123456789"
    return Py_strhex(a,10)
```

Then from Python:

```
import modulename
modulename.test()
```

**This works fine without a segmentation fault**; therefore I'm pretty convinced this code is fine.

I do not know how you're calling the Cython code since you do not say; however Cython does not generate C code with the intention that you just copy an individual function. It generates a module and the module expects to be imported (some stuff is set up during the module import). Specifically Cython sets up a table of strings during module initialization including the string `"hex"` used to look up the attribute. To correctly use this code [you'd need to ensure the module it's contained in is imported first](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations) rather than just dump a copy of the generate Cython code in a C file. Doing this is a bit complicated in Python 3 and probably doesn't suit your purposes.

I'll leave this answer in it's current state since I believe it's correct and the issues are occurring in the parts you don't specify. It's quite likely it isn't useful to you and you're free to ignore it.

Comment: Wouldn’t this fails if argbuf is passed to the stack (because it would later be attempted to freed by the garbage collector) ? Also of course, I’m using lastest version of PyPy3. But as you can see in the backtrace, the Segfault happens because of the attempt to call the interpter for finding the function to be executed.

Comment: Strings own their own memory. This creates a temporary string with a copy of `argbuf` (which can be safely outlive `argbuf`, but in this case doesn't need to). The hex string derived from it is also separate and owns its own memory. From a memory management point of view it's fine as long as `argbuf` is valid the moment the function is called. I'm afraid this is only an attempt to answer the "how to write a Cython function to convert `const char*` to hex" part of the question. I'm _really_ not capable to diagnosing PyPy internals issues!

Comment: As shown by the backtrace sounds like the real issue if about doing in full C without calling python getattr (which also means without using cython). I mean doing it in full C compatible with Cpython 3.2 (something I’ve no idea on how to acheive).

Comment: If the Cython code still produces a seg-fault then I don't think I can help you; I'll delete my answer fairly shortly

Comment: No it might still be possible to edit it. What I can do is to convert in hex using C strings then convert into a python string. Which boils down to this question : how to convert a C string into a PyObject string ? Beside, are you sure `(argbuf[:arglen])` returns a bytearray and not a str object ?

Comment: If you look at the generated C code then `(argbuf[:arglen])` translates to a call to [`PyBytes_FromStringAndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_FromStringAndSize), so it gives you a `bytes` object. You could obviously then call `encode` on that to convert to a `str`

Comment: I do confirm your code crash the same way than in my question. Please delete this answer in order to mark the question as fully unanswered.

Comment: I've managed to do some more testing and my view is the code works fine at least in a simple test case - see the edit. I realise that it doesn't solve your problem

Comment: Did you try to run tests.py from pysha3 with this code in backports.inc using official Python?

Comment: No - I ran a very simple test as specified in the edit. I don't believe just copying this code into backports.inc will work (because Cython will expect it to be in an imported module)

Comment: I was meaning the resulting C code of cythonize, not python code directly of course.

Comment: OK. Just ran `tests.py` of pysha3, and it crash in the official Python3 implementation too. So it’s definitely linked to a problem arising from using Cython.